# Disable Universal Clipboard temporarily

Tags: ios, macos, clipboard, nspasteboard

iOS and macOS have a built in feature called Universal Clipboard that syncs the clipboard's content across devices using iCloud.

```
NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects("Test 123")
```

I would like to write something to the general pasteboard on my Cocoa app to share it across apps without it being synced with other iCloud devices. I wasn't able to find a way to do it. In fact I think it is not possible without the user disabling it manually in the settings.

The docs say:

> The general pasteboard, available by way of the general class method, automatically participates with the Universal Clipboard feature in macOS 10.12 and later and in iOS 10.0 and later. There is no macOS API for interacting with this feature.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard

But maybe there is a workaround, a private API (no App Store, I know) or something else someone might know about. :)

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the general pasteboard is available to all apps, but the NSPasteboard can be used to create private pasteboards. All you need to do is:

```
let myPasteboard = NSPasteboard(name: NSPasteboard.Name("mypasteboard"))
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1531026-init). Thus, you can copy the pasted item to your private pasteboard and, only when you want it, you can then transfer the data to the general pasteboard and make the data available to all apps.

However, if you want to prevent the Universal Clipboard from being shared across devices, all you have to do is:

```
let generalPasteboard = NSPasteboard.general

// current host only
generalPasteboard.prepareForNewContents(with: .currentHostOnly)
// write here to the pasteboard
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a good solution if you don't want to share the pasteboard with other apps. In my case I want to share the pasteboard with other apps, but not not with other devices using Universal Clipboard. If anyone has a solution for that, please let us know. :)

Comment: Then you should have said so from the beginning. Yes, there is a solution. I will edit my answer, but you should edit your question too. ;)

Comment: That’s why I said I want to use the general pasteboard. :) Thanks for the update. I can’t believe I didn’t stumble across that function which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That is why SO exists, for a rainy day when we miss something or someone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For active usersession use SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser.
The library is libplist which is crossplatform. This code allows you to disable clipboard sharing or enable. Purely in C++ code.

```
// Assemble some arguments
const std::string plistPath = "/Users/" + activeUserSession + "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist";
const std::string baseCommand = "defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist ClipboardSharingEnabled";
plist_t root_node = NULL;

// Read the plist file
int status = plist_read_from_file(plistPath.c_str(), &root_node, NULL);

// File doesn't exist, let's write a flag with the feature enabled (as that is the default value on mac)
if (status)
{
    // Create a new beautiful dictionary
    plist_t dict = plist_new_dict();

    // Set the initial value for ClipboardSharingEnabled to "1"
    plist_dict_set_item(dict, "ClipboardSharingEnabled", plist_new_string("1"));

    // Write the plist to the file
    status = plist_write_to_file(dict, plistPath.c_str(), PLIST_FORMAT_BINARY, PLIST_OPT_NONE);
    if (status != PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // If our file attempt for some reason would fail, let's try it with the shell as well just in case...
        status = system((baseCommand + " " + "1").c_str());
    }

    // Free
    plist_free(dict);

    // PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS is 0, so success applies for system() call as well
    if (status != PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS)
        throw here
}

// Prepare for reading
plist_t read_root_node = NULL;
plist_format_t originalFormat;
status = plist_read_from_file(plistPath.c_str(), &read_root_node, &originalFormat);
char *clipboardSharingValue = NULL;

// If read was successful
if (status == PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS)
{
    // Check if the ClipboardSharingEnabled key exists and It's an actual string
    plist_t clipboardSharingEnabledItem = plist_dict_get_item(read_root_node, "ClipboardSharingEnabled");
    if (clipboardSharingEnabledItem && plist_get_node_type(clipboardSharingEnabledItem) == PLIST_STRING)
    {
        // Retrieve the current value
        plist_get_string_val(clipboardSharingEnabledItem, &clipboardSharingValue);
    }

    // Check state
    bool isEnabled = std::string(clipboardSharingValue) == "1";
    if (isEnabled != enableClipboardSharing)
    {
        // Determine value to set
        const std::string valueToSet = enableClipboardSharing ? "1" : "0";

        // Write the desired value (0/1) as a string to ClipboardSharingEnabled in read_root_node and save
        plist_dict_set_item(read_root_node, "ClipboardSharingEnabled", plist_new_string(valueToSet.c_str()));

        // Save the updated plist to the file
        status = plist_write_to_file(read_root_node, plistPath.c_str(), originalFormat, PLIST_OPT_NONE);
        if (status != PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS)
            // If our file attempt for some reason would fail, let's try it with the shell as well just in case...
            status = system((baseCommand + " " + valueToSet).c_str());
    }

    // Destruct a plist_t node and all its children recursively
    plist_free(read_root_node);

    // PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS is 0, so success applies for system() call as well
    if (status != PLIST_ERR_SUCCESS)
        throw here

}
else
    throw here
```